# labels not working in tlinker by using if

Tags: tkinter, python-3.7

I am trying to do experiments with tkinter, but my code isn't working. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

frame = tk.Frame(master=window, width=150, height=150)
frame.pack()

label1 = tk.Label(master=frame, text="I'm at (0, 0)", bg="red")
label1.place(x=0, y=0)

label2 = tk.Label(master=frame, text="I'm at (75, 75)", bg="yellow")
Question = input("your question")
if Question == ("yes"):
    print ("well done")
elif Question == ("no"):
    print ("try again")
    label3 = tk.Label(master=frame, text="I'm at (75, 75)", bg="yellow")
    label3.place(x=75, y=75)
    
    
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is your full error?

Comment: *"my code isn't working"* is not a good description of your problem.

Comment: _Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?_ you are using `input`... while making a GUI

Answer (score 0):

The `input` can be substituted to `tk.Entry` while making GUI The input is merely used for console. I added one more feature and additional widgets to `tk.Label`, `tkEntry` and `en.bind`. I substituted in your code and will re-wrote into my code.

Here is code:

```
import tkinter as tk


window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('500x200')

frame = tk.Frame(master=window, width=190, height=150)
frame.pack()

lbl = tk.Label(master=frame, text="Answer yes or no in entry box", bg='black', fg="white")
lbl.place(x=5, y=0)

label1 = tk.Label(master=frame, text="I'm at (0, 0)", bg="red")
 
en = tk.Entry(frame, width=25)
en.place(x=125, y=30)
out = tk.StringVar()

def _get(event):
    global p
    p = en.get()
    if p == ("yes"):
        label1.place(x=50, y=30)
        out = "well done"       
    elif p == ("no"):
        out = "try again" 
        label2.place(x=75, y=50)
    label3.configure(text=out)    
                        
en.bind('<Return>' , _get)

label2 = tk.Label(master=frame, text="I'm at (75, 75)", bg="yellow")

label3 = tk.Label(master=frame, text="",  bg="yellow")
label3.place(x=75, y=80)
   
window.mainloop()
```

Just press enter.

Result for yes:

[image]

Result for no:

[image]